What permissions do I need for facebook activity history?
Wondering can anyone point me in the right direction here. I am trying to access the activity endpoint of the facebook marketing api and keep getting a missing permissions error.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-activity/
Can anyone help or point me to what I am doing wrong?
I am following this stack so think I am right in graph endpoint:
Using the Activity Log Endpoint in the Facebook Marketing APIs
Endpoint I am creating looks like this in python:
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/act_{account_id}/activities?access_token={access_token}"

I have tried recreating my token and giving all permissions to it and still getting the same error so not sure what I am missing. Can someone point me to the permissions required for it? This is the error I'm seeing:
Here is the error:
{'error': {'message': '(#100) Missing permissions', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'Aa6zg3SUnxRo_rLBI6EQTtA'}}


Standard Access ads_read and ads_management permissions are sufficient for managing your ad account. To manage other ad accounts, you’ll need Advanced Access permissions.
Ref: https://blog.coupler.io/facebook-ads-api/

Hi Lokesh,
Thanks for that. Do you happen to know what advanced access is needed? I can't find anywhere what specific access is required. Is it advanced access to the marketing api or specific permissions from the user granted?

I got the access tokens with below permissions ads_management, business_management, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads. After that I have tried the url https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/act_{account_id}/activities?access_token={access_token}  it worked for me.

Also, complete Business Verification for your account.  I am not sure business verification is really need but my account has already bussiness verified so I think that might be required.
